# Condition statement in the view error

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

How can I specify in the view to show saved title only if description exists?

```
:input_html => { :value => "#{@description.title}" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:input_html => { :value => "#{@description.try(:title)}" }
```

you could also write something like: `description.title if description`

but it looks like you are using `simple_form` gem, and in this case something like `f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'special' }` should automatically set value if it exists.